# Spring boot: add an external configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to build a new annotation based spring boot application.

On the DAO-level I have a configuration class with Dao beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    ...
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean 
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
    template.setDataSource(dataSource());

    return template;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource)
{
    ....
}


@Bean
public PersonDao personDao(){
    return new PersonDao();
}
}
```

On the server level a controller and a Mein class.

```
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("my.package")
@Import(DataBaseConfig.class)
public class Main {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);        
    }
}
```

The problem is that the main class does not see the beans got from the DatabaseConfig and that's why cannot start the application (because they are user in the controller). How can I correctly import them?

Comment: could you please provide full package name for each class, including Main, DatabaseConfig and your Controller?

Comment: for example: DatabaseConfig - my.package.dao.config; Main - my.package.server; Controller - my.package.server.controller

Comment: Can you please try to move your Main.java to package `my.package` instead of `my.package.server`?

Comment: may be i need to list all my packages in componentScan annotation? 
I thought that if a set a general package, it would work